# I need a regex or method to remove sequential quotes from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex or some kind of a method to remove sequential quotes.

Example: *""I am in" a quote"" to "I am in a quote"*

Or ""I am in quotes"" to "I am in quotes."

I do not know much about regular expressions. I also tried using the replace method but have trouble escaping stuff.

I have been experimenting with this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"^\s*""?|""?\s*$";
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: What would make the quote after `in` sequential in any way?

Comment: It seems you are removing all the quotes. `""I am in" a quote""` has an odd number of quotes, so the result should be `"I am in a quote""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Split` by `"` first then `Join` them together:

```
var result = string.Format("\"{0}\"", string.Join("", x.Split('"')));
```

For example, your input:

```
""I am in" a quote""
```

Using `Split` with `"`, you will have a list of string which does not contains `"` anymore. Then when you use `Join` with `""`, it means you joins them together again by empty string instead of `"`.

The first result does not have `"` at first and last, use `string.Format` to add `"` to first and last to get the final result.

Another simpler approach which uses `Replace` and `PadLeft` and `PadRight`

```
 string output = input.Replace("\"", string.Empty)
                      .PadLeft(1, '"')
                      .PadRight(1, '"');
```

Comment: Won't that just remove _all_ quotes?

Comment: @Coung Le! This works exactly as I was hoping: Just out of curiosity, How would you make this conditional, so that it only applies to string formatted with the quotes? Either way, thanks for your knowledge. Guy!

Comment: If you just want to remove the quotes from a string, there's no point in using `Split()` and `Join()`. This is just a more complicated way of doing `"\"" + x.Replace("\"", "") + "\""`

Comment: @JLRishe: You are right, you were commenting while I am middle of editing to add another approach:

Comment: @CuongLe: If I have something like this: "Hello","World" then the two middle quotes are stripped to: "Hello world". Which is what I asked, so I am not complaining. Just looking at possibilities. In the future I hope to modify this so that if it is like this: "Hello","World", meaning if the two quotes are separated by a comma than do not format.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: That would be a little more complicated, you can post another question for this

Comment: Another question? Why in the world would he do that? That was the question.

Answer (score -2):

hey I am in constant use of Regex where I work and i think this Regex will do the job.

```
 .*?(")".*?
```

after that you can pull it or replace it.

Comment: You match a pair of quotes and put the first in a capture group?